# Trying to get Scite to work, this pops up: javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, scite

I'm using Windows 10 and I am required to start using Scite for a class at my university. I've been using intelliJ and that works fine, but for the class our professor strictly wants us to use Scite. Anytime I compile code I get the error:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I went into my Environment variables and my PATH variable is set to:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? I haven't got Scite to work in 2 months.

Comment: `javac` is part of the JDK, not of the JRE .

Comment: Good catch.  Your path should be set to something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` (note the JDK instead of JRE in the file names).  Although oddly my path seems to be set to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.  Not sure what that is, some sort of universal path indirection deely.

Comment: I took your advice and changed the path to the JDK folder, however, code still won't compile and the same error pops up.